# Can validation in keras.fit run in multiprocess to speed things up?

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I am practicing the codes in Chapter 6 in "Deep Learning with Python" (by François Chollet). Things are running on colab, but the validation takes a very long time.

Here I only show the codes that are relevant to the question. The complete code can be found in [the author's github](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.ipynb)

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

lookback = 1440

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(32, input_shape=(None, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss="mae")

train_gen = {some generator function}
val_gen = {some generator function}

val_steps = (300000 - 200001 - lookback)

history = model.fit(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=500, epochs=20, validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps=val_steps)
```

The training took several seconds, but the validation took 20 mins per epoch, because there are 98559 steps of them.

[image: screenshot]

I tried "use_multiprocessing=True" as in:

```
history = model.fit(..., use_multiprocessing=True)
```

or "workers=10" as in:

```
history = model.fit(..., workers=10)
```

But they didn't help, and took even longer.

So I wonder, whether there are ways to speed the validation up?

Comment: your code is not complete, what is `val_gen` `val_steps` and `train_gen`?

Comment: In this case, I am only curious about hints to speed up the validation in model.fit(). Posting all downloading and the previous preprocessing in the question seems unnecessary. I provide the link in the question.

Comment: There's no way to speed up the validation you are doing right now. Most logical thing to do is decrease the amount of validation steps or increase the amount of training steps per epoch. Having a train - 500 steps to a validate - 98559 steps ratio doesn't make any sense to me anyways. Maybe set `val_steps` = `500` or something, and after your network has converged, you can validate on the entire dataset?